# How T Transpose Multiple Columns Values by Groups between groups delimiters in adjacent Column Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have the following minimal example data (in reality 100's of groups) in range `A1:P9` (same data in range `A14:A22)`:

[image: 2]

## With Sample `A1:AR9`:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 61 | 219 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 4 | 2 | : | 61 | 219 |  |  | 26 | 26 | 26 | 94 |  |  | 21 | 33 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 4 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 94 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 2 | : | 154 | 26 |  |  | 40 | 19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 21 | 33 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 14 | 1 | 2 | 3 | : | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 |  |  | 23 |  |  | 23 | 4 |  | 6 | 28 |
|  | 2 | 154 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 40 | 19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 14 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 1 | 23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 2 | 23 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 20 | 28 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

## Or Sample `A14:AQ22`:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 61 | 219 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | : | 61 | 219 | 4 | : | 26 | 26 | 26 | 94 | 2 | : | 21 | 33 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 4 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 94 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | : | 154 | 26 | 2 | : | 40 | 19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 21 | 33 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 14 | : | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 | 1 | : | 23 | 2 | : | 23 | 4 | : | 3 | 6 | 20 |
|  | 2 | 154 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 40 | 19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 14 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 38 | 26 | 32 | 87 | 39 | 54 | 38 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 1 | 23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 2 | 23 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 20 | 28 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I need the output as shown in range `Q1:AR3` or as in range `Q14:AQ16`.

Basically, at each group delimited/inbetween values in Column A, I would need:

- The intemediary adjacent values in Column B to be transposed horizontally
- And the adjacent content of Columns C to P (14 Columns, at least) to be "joined" together horizontaly an sequencialy "per group", including the content of the delimiter's row (in Column A).
- As a bonus it would be really nice to have the Transposed data followed by a `:`, and each sub Content of Columns C to P to be also separated by a `|` (as shown in screenshot `Q1:AR3` or `Q14:AR16`).

(Or if it's more feasible, alternatively, the simpler to read 2nd model as in `A14:AQ22`).

I have a really hard time putting together a formula to come to the expected result.

All I could think of was:

- Transposing Column B's content by getting the rows of the adjacent Cells with values in column A,
- Concatenating with the Column letter,
- Duplicating it in a new column, and Filtering out the blank intermediary cells,
- Then shifting the duplicated column 1 cell up,
- Then concatenating within a `TRANSPOSE` formula to get the range of the groups,
- Then finally transposing all the groups from Columns B in a new Colum

(very convoluted but I couldn't find better way).

To get to that input:

```
=TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)
=TRANSPOSE(B4:B5)
=TRANSPOSE(B7:B9)
```

That was already a very manual and error prone process, and still I could not successfully think of how to do the remaining content joining of Column C to P in a formula.

I tested the following approach but it's not working and would be very tedious process to fix to go and to implement on large datasets:

```
=TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)&": "&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C1:P1, NOT(C2:P2 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C2:P2, NOT(C2:P2 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C43:P3, NOT(C3:P3 = "") ))
=TRANSPOSE(B4:B5)&": "&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C4:P4, NOT(C4:P4 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C5:P5, NOT(C5:P5 = "") ))
=TRANSPOSE(B6:B9)&": "&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C6:P6, NOT(C6:P6 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C7:P7, NOT(C7:P7 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C8:P8, NOT(C8:P8 = "") ))&JOIN( " | " , FILTER(C8:P8, NOT(C9:P9 = "") ))
```

What better approach to favor toward the expected result? Preferably with a Formula, or if not possible with a script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Typos in table and picture. Just fixed it.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: Sure. Here's a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t41X8vwJFUNt6hsB3SbHelCKe1tBAM9aIBj9qNspk0I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry guys for the the 1st table in the post. For some reason it displays funny at the end. I'll let it as is as it's the 2nd time I try to fix if to no avail and I think it should be clear enough to understand. If not please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sample 1 try this out:

`=LAMBDA(norm,MAP(UNIQUE(norm),LAMBDA(ζ,{TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B1:B9,norm=ζ)),":",SPLIT(BYROW(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(BYROW(C1:P9,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN("ζ",1,r))),norm=ζ)),LAMBDA(rr,TEXTJOIN("γ|γ",1,rr))),"ζγ")})))(SORT(SCAN(,SORT(A1:A9,ROW(A1:A9),),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c))),ROW(A1:A9),))`

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251678/discussion-on-answer-by-ztiaa-how-t-transpose-multiple-columns-values-by-groups); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.